# express-locale always returns default - why?

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I've installed express-locale

```
npm install --save express-locale
```

and configure it like this:

```
app = express();
app.use(locale({
    priority: ['accept-language', 'cookie', 'domain', 'default']
}));
```

but when a page is called:

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.locale);
});
```

I always get:

> { code: 'en_GB', source: 'default' }

no matter how I change my browser's preferred language.  I've looked at the code in this module and I see a reference to `req.acceptedLanguages` (when trying to resolve for 'accept-language'), which in my case always returns undefined (which explains why it goes for default), but what I don't understand is if I look at

```
console.log(req.header('Accept-Language'));
```

I get:

> sv,en-GB;q=0.8,en;q=0.6,es;q=0.4,fr;q=0.2,ast;q=0.2,en-US;q=0.2

from which it's clear I should have Swedish as my primary language... so what is wrong with this?

as a separate but related question: even if `req.acceptedLanguages` returned a value, it would be without a locale.  in fact, `sv` is not sufficient to deduce a locale since Swedish is spoken in Sweden (`sv-SE`) and Finland (`sv-FI`).  why does this matter? because I'm trying to display a price and it needs to be in the currency of the user (Sweden = kroner, Finland = Euro), but without a locale I can't figure it out.  how is this generally done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reached out to the author and got back something useful, see: https://github.com/smhg/express-locale/issues/4

> The req.acceptedLanguages issue is Express 4-specific and solved in
>   c17d901. It hasn't been published to npm as we first need to add
>   Express 3 and Express 4 specific tests. Should be coming up shortly.
>
> Add this to your package.json to test the recent changes:
>
> "express-locale": "git://github.com/smhg/express-locale#c17d901"